# Video plays in QuickTime but not in Itunes

Tags: itunes, audio, screen, quicktime, mp4

This video plays just fine in Quicktime but in Itunes the video plays but the screen stays black. The audio however, does play just fine. I think my video has the right codec?

[image: Video specs]

Comment: Could you try VLC?

Comment: Yeah it works fine in VLC Mediaplayer too, nothing wrong, just not in itunes. I do have to say it was original a mkv file but i converted it with handbrake to mp4